# Changing Phaser state from the outside

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas, phaser-framework

Because I need some user input in my game, I have an html form that I overlay on top of the game. When clicking the cancel button in the form, I want to change to a different state (and remove the form).

I cannot call something like `this.game.state.start('mainscreen')`, because the form is outside of Phaser and so it doesn't know what `this.game` is.

I can do it by calling `Phaser.GAMES[0].state.start("MainScreen")`, but this feels not right. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the variable that holds your game is named `yourGame` and is declared inside `window`, you should be able to call `yourGame.state.start("YourState")` from anywhere.